# SG 90 not working

Tags: servo

I have tried almost everything but the servo is not moving at all
here is my schematics
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/arcaegecengiz/how-to-use-servo-motors-with-arduino-b02bed

Here is my code

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see your schematics, since they seem to be in fritzing format (fzz?) and I don't have that program. So please include the schematic as image in your question. Also, since that is a schematic from a tutorial, a good quality, in focus picture of your actual setup (where we can see the actual connections) might be good. Your code seems to be the standard sweep example. I don't see much to troubleshoot there